SpringAmqp create rabbitmq channel timeout
I want to use Jmeter to test my RabbitMq server but get some error, my RabbitMq deploy with Docker and use default config, i use SpringBoot 3 project with virtual thread to send message to rabbitmq.
parent project pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.chico</groupId>
    <artifactId>zk_mqtt_rabbitmq</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>mqtt_emqx</module>
        <module>mqtt_main</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

main module pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.chico</groupId>
        <artifactId>zk_mqtt_rabbitmq</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>mqtt_main</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.chico.confugure</groupId>
            <artifactId>mqtt_emqx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.chico.MqttApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

rabbitmq config file
vm_memory_high_watermark.relative = 0.8
vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio = 0.9
log.file.level = error
default_user = username
default_pass = password

Service
@Service
@Slf4j
public class RabbitMqMessageService {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private final DirectExchange directExchange;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public RabbitMqMessageService(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, @Qualifier(RabbitMqConstants.IotDevDataExchange) DirectExchange directExchange, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.directExchange = directExchange;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public void sendDataMessage(RmDevStatusBO statusBO) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String messageStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(statusBO);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(directExchange.getName(), RabbitMqConstants.IotDevDataRouteKey, messageStr);
    }

}

CachingConnectionFactoryConfigurer
public class RabbitMqCachingConnectionFactoryConfigurer extends CachingConnectionFactoryConfigurer {

    private final RabbitMqChannelListener rabbitMqChannelListener;
    private final RabbitMqConnectListener rabbitMqConnectListener;

    public RabbitMqCachingConnectionFactoryConfigurer(RabbitProperties properties, RabbitConnectionDetails connectionDetails,
                                                      RabbitMqChannelListener rabbitMqChannelListener, RabbitMqConnectListener rabbitMqConnectListener) {
        super(properties, connectionDetails);
        this.rabbitMqChannelListener = rabbitMqChannelListener;
        this.rabbitMqConnectListener = rabbitMqConnectListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RabbitProperties rabbitProperties) {
        super.configure(connectionFactory, rabbitProperties);
      connectionFactory.addConnectionListener(rabbitMqConnectListener);
        connectionFactory.addChannelListener(rabbitMqChannelListener);
// VirtualPool.pool = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()
        connectionFactory.setExecutor(VirtualPool.pool);
    }

}

application.yml
spring:
  threads:
    virtual:
      enabled: true

  rabbitmq:
    host: ipaddr
    port: 5672
    username: root
    password: pwd
    template:
      mandatory: true
      retry:
        enabled: true
    publisher-returns: true

when i use Jmeter to test the sendDataMessage method  (send 20000 requests in 5 seconds) and first i get the channelMax limit exception and then i get the channel create timeout exception.
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpResourceNotAvailableException: The channelMax limit is reached. Try later.
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:60)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:679)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:645)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:534)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1478)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2255)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2222)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1181)
    at com.chico.rabbitmq.service.RabbitMqMessageService.sendDataMessage(RabbitMqMessageService.java:36)
    at com.chico.emqx.component.ClientListener.handleMessageArrived(ClientListener.java:27)
    at com.chico.confugure.component.AbstractMqttMessageListener.lambda$messageArrived$0(AbstractMqttMessageListener.java:11)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on channel AMQChannel(amqp://username@ipaddr:5672/,1433) (#1433) timed out
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:69)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1473)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:679)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:645)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:534)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1478)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2255)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2222)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1181)
    at com.chico.rabbitmq.service.RabbitMqMessageService.sendDataMessage(RabbitMqMessageService.java:36)
    at com.chico.emqx.component.ClientListener.handleMessageArrived(ClientListener.java:27)
    at com.chico.confugure.component.AbstractMqttMessageListener.lambda$messageArrived$0(AbstractMqttMessageListener.java:11)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ChannelContinuationTimeoutException: Continuation call for method #method<channel.open>(out-of-band=) on channel AMQChannel(amqp://username@ipaddr:5672/,1433) (#1433) timed out
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrapTimeoutException(AMQChannel.java:336)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:318)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:152)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:136)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:189)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:638)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:58)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:552)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:316)
    ... 22 common frames omitted

and the rabbitmq dashboard has so many channels that cann't be automatically closed,
enter image description here
The total number of channels has exceeded the maximum supported cache by the client by 25.
and when i use jconsole to monitor my application , i get some exceptions.
the forkjoinpool used to payload virtual threads is running at full capacity. (from ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 to ForkJoinPool-1-worker-256)
名称: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-256
状态: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f5da3bc上的WAITING
总阻止数: 2, 总等待数: 8

堆栈跟踪: 
java.base@21.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1893)
java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1809)
java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)


and my applicaiton can't respond to any other requests defined in the controller and blocks the request util they timeout.
I capture all the thread stack when the forkjoinpool runs in full capacity. I'll show just a few of them, the file is too large.
From file dumped by VisualVm
"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3" - Thread t@75
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at java.base@21.0.2/jdk.internal.vm.Continuation.run(Continuation.java:251)
    - waiting to lock <6d9bee2f> (a java.lang.VirtualThread) owned by "" t@267
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.VirtualThread.runContinuation(VirtualThread.java:221)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.VirtualThread$$Lambda/0x00007f7e10474600.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1423)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
    at java.base@21.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

From file dumped by jcmd tool
#267 "" virtual
      java.base/java.lang.Object.wait0(Native Method)
      java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:366)
      com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:73)
      com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
      com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:552)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:316)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:152)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:136)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:189)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:638)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:58)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1473)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:700)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:679)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:645)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:534)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1478)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2255)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2222)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1122)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1188)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1181)
      com.chico.rabbitmq.service.RabbitMqMessageService.sendDataMessage(RabbitMqMessageService.java:36)
      com.chico.emqx.component.ClientListener.handleMessageArrived(ClientListener.java:27)
      com.chico.confugure.component.AbstractMqttMessageListener.lambda$messageArrived$0(AbstractMqttMessageListener.java:11)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
      java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)

#7161 "" virtual
      java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.park(VirtualThread.java:582)
      java.base/java.lang.System$2.parkVirtualThread(System.java:2643)
      java.base/jdk.internal.misc.VirtualThreads.park(VirtualThreads.java:54)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:219)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:754)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:990)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:153)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:322)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.writeFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:207)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.writeFrame(AMQConnection.java:649)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:150)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:503)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:479)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingRpc(AMQChannel.java:378)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:366)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:305)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:152)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:136)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:189)
      com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:638)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SimpleConnection.createChannel(SimpleConnection.java:58)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1473)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:700)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:679)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:645)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:534)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1478)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2255)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2222)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1122)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1188)
      org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1181)
      com.chico.rabbitmq.service.RabbitMqMessageService.sendDataMessage(RabbitMqMessageService.java:36)
      com.chico.emqx.component.ClientListener.handleMessageArrived(ClientListener.java:27)
      com.chico.confugure.component.AbstractMqttMessageListener.lambda$messageArrived$0(AbstractMqttMessageListener.java:11)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
      java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)

From file dumped by jstack tool
"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3" #75 [77] daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=917.14ms elapsed=39.72s tid=0x00007f7e540014a0  [0x00007f7e5ced8000]
   Carrying virtual thread #7161
    at jdk.internal.vm.Continuation.run(java.base@21.0.2/Continuation.java:251)
    at java.lang.VirtualThread.runContinuation(java.base@21.0.2/VirtualThread.java:221)
    at java.lang.VirtualThread$$Lambda/0x00007f7e10474600.run(java.base@21.0.2/Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(java.base@21.0.2/ForkJoinTask.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(java.base@21.0.2/ForkJoinTask.java:387)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(java.base@21.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:1312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(java.base@21.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:1843)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(java.base@21.0.2/ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(java.base@21.0.2/ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

As you can see there is some relationship between "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3" and virtual thread 267 and virtual thread 7161, but I don't think it's a deadlock, because running the same code in a local window environment doesn't happen, no matter how many times I test it.
So could it be due to the limitations of some resources of docker containers?
When the client creates a channel timeout, I can see on the server panel that the channel with the same ID has been created and it cannot be automatically closed, but the rule is that it has exceeded the default 25 channel cache and should be automatically closed.
So I'm guessing that the carrier thread is blocking because the client didn't receive the "channel.open-ok" fram causing the virtual thread to go into the wait method.
BlockingCell.java
public synchronized T get(long timeout) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        if (timeout == INFINITY) return get();

        if (timeout < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Timeout cannot be less than zero");
        }

        long now = System.nanoTime() / NANOS_IN_MILLI;
        long maxTime = now + timeout;
        while (!_filled && (now = (System.nanoTime() / NANOS_IN_MILLI)) < maxTime) {
            wait(maxTime - now);
        }

        if (!_filled)
            throw new TimeoutException();

        return _value;
    }

This is just my guess, I haven't found the cause of the problem yet. And when i use platform executor to handle the message, the application work normally without any error.
ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 40, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());


Could you paste into the text of your question the source code of RabbitMqMessageService and RabbitMqCachedConnectionFactoryConfigurer classes instead of images? Also, a relevant part of your pom.xml or equivalent is desirable to understand what version of Spring Boot/RabbitMQ and others you are using.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I was not able to download the artefact com.chico.confugure, don't know is it relevant or not. What is VirtualPool.pool and what does it do? if you use Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() to configure the executor is the behavior the same? If you use platform Executor, for example, Executors.newCachedThreadPool is the behavior the same?

@igor.zh com.chico is the package of the project, and mqtt_emqx is another module of the parent project. VirtualPool.pool is a virtual thread pool used to handle message from EMQX and forward to rabbitmq. This is the main logic of the project.
